# Best way to stop "xss"-hackers and similar

Tags: security, web, xss

I've noticed yesterday by looking into my apache error log that someone tried to get access to the website via calling a lot of sites like:

```
mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin
mywebsite.com/dbadmin
mywebsite.com/mysqladmin
mywebsite.com/foo.php#some-javascript
...
```

This caused a lot of 404 errors. What's the best way to stop them doing so?
I thought about creating a fake-phpmyadmin dir with some php code that bans their ip address from my website when accessing this dir for about 12 to 24 h.

Is there a better way to deal with this kind of guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really prevent people from trying these sorts of attacks. The best you can do is log all these sorts of attempts like you're currently doing and maybe implement some sort of temporary blacklisting.

The security of your site shouldn't depend on people not trying to do these sorts of attacks, since you will never be able to fully prevent them.

Comment: yes I'm aware of the fact that I will not be able to stop this people from doing so. But I can make it harder for them

Comment: Yeah, and blacklisting them temporarily is the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), it's pretty easy to set up in Apache.

Comment: this module looks promissing, I will take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

If none of those exist, they're not gonna be able to do anything. You just have to worry about them being able to access parts that do exist and that you don't want them to access. Or using your poorly written scripts with XSS holes in it.

You could make it harder on them by checking if they're trying to access a common XSS path (like phpMyAdmin's normal path) and use an alternate 404 page that has malicious javascript on it or something.

Comment: Yes I'm also aware of that fact, but when they have a list that tries alot of possibilities like above its very likely that they will hit one of 1000 dirs and try to do another attack. if they access 3 non-existing sites and I black list them, they will fail accessing the right dir on the 95x trial.